# Camera: How to stop the player turn up and down on y-axis in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

How can I stop the character turning and tilting with the camera in the y-axis? I mean I want to be able to look up and down without changing the player position. It's ok to have it turning around on the x-axis (left and right).
Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Actions : MonoBehaviour
{
        public float speedH = 2.0f;
        public float speedV = 2.0f;

        private float yaw = 0.0f;
        private float pitch = 2.0f;

        private void Update()
        {
            yaw += speedH * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
            pitch = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

            pitch = Mathf.Clamp(pitch, -30f, 45f);

            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(pitch, yaw, 0.0f);

        }
        private void Start()
        {
        }
}
```

Comment: Is this really your current code? I don't think this will compile. You have the `Update` function twice. If you don't want to rotate around the x axis then remove the pitch code and replace x axis with 0.

Comment: `remove the pitch code and replace x axis with 0.` as Programmer said.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an empty game object and parent the camera to it. Then I would use a script to move the obj to the player's position and then rotate the obj based on the mouse input axis.

Comment: Yes, I did that but my object rotates with the camera and I want to make it stay still. For example if I look up my object tilts on its back instead of staying on its feet.

Comment: The player object or an empty object.